Why can't I buy ETH on Rice Wallet?
I don't have much experience with crypto and I quickly came across a problem. I have a USDT balance on my wallet on the Rice Wallet app. I need ETH, but I can't exchange the USDT for ETH. A message appears saying that I don't have enough ETH to pay the gas fees. How do I get the ETH onto my wallet now?

Transaction fees on the Ethereum network have to paid with ether. If the USDT are on mainnet someone will have to transfer some ether to pay for the transfer fees.

Whenever you make transactions on the blockchain, you have to pay for the processing of the transactions. These fees are called "gas fees". The fees are typically paid in the blockchain's native asset - and in the case of Ethereum, that native asset is ETH.
The way you pay the fee is by having enough ETH balance in your wallet, and when you make a transaction your ETH balance is automatically deducted for the fee.
So, in order to make any transaction (for example swapping your USDT), you have to have some ETH in your wallet first.
You need to figure out how to get ETH to your wallet in order to be able to exchange the USDT (for ETH). Yes, this is a bit awkward, but this is just how blockchains operate.

Thank you very much. I had understood that beforehand. What gave me difficulties was that I needed ETH to get ETH. How is that supposed to work if you can't buy ETH? In the end I managed to buy ETH using another app and transfer it to my wallet. Now I can pay my fees and carry on working. But I still don't understand why I managed it with one app and not the other!

There are ways to go around that limitation, but it's not easy to accomplish. In theory it's possible that some app does that magic for you, while others don't. But don't really know.
